# run one command and execute another after first killed by CTRL C in bash

Tags: linux, bash, jobs

I need to start a service1 in bash commandline. After a while I dont need that service anymore
and I do a CTRL-C to stop it. The service started another background service2. To stop that I usually do a "killall service2" after service1 has been stopped. Can I do that in one commandline like so?:

```
#: service1; killall service2
```

The above doesn't work because if I do a CTRL-C the second part (killall) gets never executed.

Comment: I know there should be something simpler, but `(trap 'cmd_2' INT; cmd_1)` should do in the meanwhile. (notice that it's the *second* command (e.g. `killall service2`) inside the trap).

Comment: `(trap : INT; cmd_1; cmd_2; cmd_3; ...)` works too. Each time you press Ctrl-C, `cmd_n` is killed and the execution continues with `cmd_n+1`.